# Commander package not parsing all options correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, github-api

I'm trying to use the NPM package Commander to build out a command line CLi tool. Unfortunately, it's not recognising all of my options, neither is it favouring my arguments (it's defaulting to the defaults somehow), I'm new to this package so some guidance would be appreciated:

I'm using the Github API to get the latest version of a specified repo, which is passed into my function which is imported into this file, I'm then trying to get whichever `--form` value is parsed and also whichever `--release` is parsed. For reference, I've got two repos: Honeycomb and Vanilla, both have completely different versions, and regardless of what I parse into `--form` it's returning the same version for `program.release`.

For example: `node scoop.js --form honeycomb` and `program.release` should give me: honeycomb 1.9.1 which is does.

On the otherhand `node scoop.js --form vanilla` and `program.release` should give me vanilla, 1.8.2

the form name is right, but it still returns `1.9.1` and I have no clue why

```js
(async () => {

  // tell the user how to use it
  program
    .name('node scoop.js')
    .usage("[options]")

  // default form
  program
    .option('-f, --form <type>', 'get the form to deploy', 'honeycomb')


  // get the latest form release
  const latestVer = await repo.latestRelease(`application-${program.form}`)

  // specify tag or use latest
  program
    .option('-r, --release <release>', 'release to deploy', latestVer)

  program.parse();


  console.log(program.form, program.release)

})()
```

Comment: I don't see any call to `.parse()`.

Comment: https://github.com/tj/commander.js#user-content-parse-and-parseasync

Comment: @Pointy That's because I've removed it for the purposes of my explanation as it was getting complex, I'll add it in, but this is besides my point, it isn't working.

Comment: Well here's one problem: until you get the **actual** `--form` argument, which won't happen until after you call `.parse()`, you can't look up the latest version from the repository. I think you'll have to change the way you're doing things, and get and (if necessary) set the version *after* you've parsed the command line.